# create new column based on two conditions from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas looking like this:

```
    A   B
0   2   0
1   0   3
2   1   1
3   5   0
4   3   1
```

I need to create a new column based on condition in column A and column B:

```
if column A > 0 and column B > 0 : new column value = 1
else : new column value = 0
```

The new column should be like this:

```
    A   B   new_column
0   2   0   0
1   0   3   0
2   1   1   1
3   5   0   0
4   3   1   1
```

I tried with **np.where** but return an error

```
df['new_column'] = np.where( (df['A']>0 & df['B']>0), 1 , 0)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

I tried **apply** but return error too:

```
def F(x):
    if x['A'] > 0 & x['B'] > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['new_column'] = df.apply(F, axis=1)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I already converted column A and column B to numeric

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'])
df['B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['B'])
```

I tried:

```
df['new_column'] = df[['A','B']].gt(0).all(1)
```

it returns True or False, not 0 / 1

Comment: `df['new_column'] = df[['A','B']].gt(0).all(1)`.

Comment: My recommendation would be `df.eval('A > 0 and B > 0').astype(int)`, there are hundreds of other ways of doing this. Please do a little research.

Comment: I made research all the day but all solutions I try didn't work, every time the error occur